# Prevent WCF *.datasource files from being checked-in

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

Since the WCF proxy generated *.datasource files give problems with long file paths when checking them into the TFS 2010 source control system, I would like to be able to add them to the list of files that, by default, are not marked as a pending add to be checked-in.

Is it possible to configure file exclusion by extension at TFS project or collection level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, found out that (at time of writing) this is a recognized wish on the backlog of the Visual Studio team:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/419915/allow-tfs-to-exclude-specific-file-extensions-from-being-add-to-source-control

That is a pitty ...

Well, i'll investigate the File Pattern exclusion policy to be deployed for this purpose: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/tfsversioncontrol/thread/03ca91cf-4332-43bb-a358-96d8fe8633dd